# Is it possible to combine two Json with Ruby in MongoDB?

Tags: json, ruby, mongodb

I have to insert documents in my Mongo database by using Ruby (not on Rails, on Notepad++), many documents have duplicates with some modifications.

I want to write a script which use a json file, read it, import it in MongoDB by checking if each documents do not have any duplicate in the database, and if there is a duplicate I want to combine it if it contains any additional information:

Such as :

Document 1

```
 { "Name" : "Lila",
    "Files":
      [
             { "Name": "File1", "Date" : "05-11-2017"},
             { "Name": "File2", "Date" : "26-03-2018"}
      ]
}
```

Document 2

```
{ "Name" : "Lila",
  "Files":
  [
         { "Name": "File3", "Date" : "26-03-2018"}
  ]
}
```

Combine them to have:

```
 { "Name" : "Lila",
   "Files":
      [
             { "Name": "File1", "Date" : "05-11-2017"},
             { "Name": "File2", "Date" : "26-03-2018"},
             { "Name": "File3", "Date" : "26-03-2018"}
      ]
  }
```

I founded that it is possible in mongo shell thanks to the aggregation-accumulation $mergeObjects, but in Ruby it do not seems to exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all the operators in ruby, too. You need to get the underlying collection object first.

```
require 'mongo' 

db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
coll = db.collection('posts')

coll.aggregate([ 
  {"$project" => {"last_name" => 1, "first_name" => 1 }}, 
  {"$match" => {"last_name" => "Jones"}}
])
```

This is an example pipeline. You can give the same aggregation pipeline that worked for you on the mongo shell to `aggregate`.

For more information, refer to the MongoDB Ruby driver documentation: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/1.8.2/Mongo%2FCollection%3Aaggregate